# Php and Mysqli - can you use a prepared statement on a SELECT clause that doesn't have a WHERE clause?

Tags: php, mysqli

```
SELECT id, title, posted, duration, thumbnail, email, first_name
FROM customers
```

Comment: While it is not necessary, you can use a prepared statement with this query and many do just for consistency.

Comment: Thank you for response Jay. How would I go about creating a prepared statement with the example SQL I posed in my question?

Comment: It depends on which API (MySQLi, PDO) you choose to use.  Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: I am using the Mysqli api.

Comment: you can't bind a table/column if that's what you're wondering/asking.

Comment: @JayBlanchard ^ and others visiting here ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I parameterize the table name in a prepared statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312737/can-i-parameterize-the-table-name-in-a-prepared-statement)

Comment: Yes, but as you have no parameters to bind why not use `mysqli_query($sql);`

Comment: I had looked at many examples online and in books. None of them show how to execute a prepared statement without a WHERE clause. Im asking if you would be kind enough to show me an example using the sample SQL I posed in my question. I'm a newbie coder and the concept of how to use a prepared statement on this sort of SQL eludes me.

Comment: tell us, is this what you want to do? `SELECT ? FROM ?` type of thing? or `SELECT cols FROM ?` @codeman

Comment: You can `prepare` any valid SQL statement. But it is only necessary to `prepare` it if 1) you want to run it many times. or 2) You want to bind parameters to placeholders i.e. `SELECT * from table WHERE id = ?`

Comment: Hello Fred thanks for response. I am trying to use a prepared statement on the sample SQL I posed in my question. Im not sure what is the correct coarse of action since there is no WHERE clause. I couldn't find any examples like the one i posed in my question.

Comment: @codeman welcome. Now, there's nothing stopping your from using `prepare()` since it is valid, but you just can't do `SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM ?` or `SELECT ?,?,? FROM ?` if that is also what you may be envisioning to do/use. There's no use or added benefit in using `prepare()` really, you can just use `query()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brief example (too long for comments) since you're using MySQLi:

Object oriented style:

```
/* prepare query */
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, title, posted, duration, thumbnail, email, first_name FROM customers");

/* execute query */
$stmt->execute();
```

Procedural style (where `$conn` is the database connection):

```
/* prepare */
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT id, title, posted, duration, thumbnail, email, first_name FROM customers");

/* execute query */
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Comment: Thank you Jay. So in this kind of SQL query, I wouldn't use question marks as place holders?

Comment: You're right @RiggsFolly, and there are other methods. I send all of my queries to a function, so `prepare()` is just part of the architecture - every query is handled by the same function.

Comment: Thank you so much Jay and Riggs for your quick response and insight much appreciated!

Comment: I knew I was right from the moment this question was posted lol

Comment: @codeman *"I wouldn't use question marks as place holders?"* - as I said a few times already and the answer is "no" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As you have no obvious reason to prepare this statement i.e. you dont say you want to run this query many times within this script and you have no placeholders for parameters to be bound to the query you can simply use `mysqli_query()` like this

```
$sql = 'SELECT id, title, posted, duration, thumbnail, email, first_name
        FROM customers';

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
    echo $row['id'];   // or whatever
}
```

> Please remember that you cannot use placeholders `?` for column names or table names, in this or in a `mysqli_prepare()` if that is what you were ultimately working up to, as @Fred-ii- has been suggesting

Answer (score 0):

Posting as a community wiki.

There's nothing stopping you from using [`prepare()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) (in MySQLi_), since it is valid.

You just can't do, and as a few examples.:

- `SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM ?`
- `SELECT ?,?,? FROM ?`
- `SELECT ?,?,? FROM table`

If you plan / envision on doing this, since that would constitute as binding a table/column which isn't allowed in prepared statements, as much as we'd like it to work as.

However, there is nothing stopping you from using what is called a "safelist".

Here are a few references:

- [Can I parameterize the table name in a prepared statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312737/can-i-parameterize-the-table-name-in-a-prepared-statement)
- [Can PHP PDO Statements accept the table or column name as parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-or-column-name-as-parameter)

In reference to using [`prepare()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) over just [`query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) can be found in the following answer for the related question:

- [MySQL prepared statement vs normal query. Gains & Losses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6301789/1415724)